# what would be url for xml suggestions

Tags: html, xml, google-maps

With this url [Google suggestions](http://google.com/complete/search?q=cars&output=toolbar)

You can get an xml suggestions list for the word `cars`

What would be the URL to limit the results to Google Maps results?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Google Geocode api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) might be what you're looking for. There's documentation on that page for xml output for search locations using queries like the following:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=<SEARCH_TERM_HERE>&sensor=true
```

It seeems very powerful. By just [searching for the town](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=portstewart&sensor=true) I live I get multiple results in xml, each containing the region, co-ordinates, area, country, post code, etc.